# Resume previous activity from broadcast receiver

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

here's my problem:

- I'm in activity A
- Activity A starts a new activity B to call a number (Intent.ACTION_CALL)
- How is it possible to resume activity A - I don't want to finish activity B, I simply want to bring activity A to the front

At the moment I have a broadcastReceiver which is able to start a new instance of activity A when the call takes place. If I start activity A from there with "FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP", I get the error

```
Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity
context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.
Is this really what you want?
```

But I don't want a new task, I want to RESUME activity A

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
Perhaps I could simply simulate a click on the BACK-button?

Comment: this could be implemented on same activity with 2 fragments/dialogfragments but dont think possible with 2 activities...

Answer (score 1):

Considering your use case - BroadcastReceiver that doesn't have a tasks in which to start the activity - `singleTask` in the manifest should do what you want.

> "singleTask"
>   The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the root of 
>   the new    task. However, if an instance of the activity already exists in a 
>   separate task, the system routes the intent to the existing instance through
>   a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance.
>   Only one instance of the activity can exist at a time.
>
> Note: Although the activity starts in a new task, the Back
>   button still returns the user to the previous activity.

Taken from:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` ?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT

It seems to do exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, I've tried this - same error
The problem seems to be, that the Phonecall-Activity has no context:
http://jonathanblog2000.blogspot.de/2011/03/use-flagactivitynewtask-flag-when.html

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the broadcastReceiver has no context (the Phonecall-Activity has the right context, but I can't manupilate it...)